# Optimizing generating a list of sums in Python

Tags: python, optimization

I am attempting to use Python for the following task: given a set of integers `S`, produce `S + S`, the set of integers expressible as `s1 + s2` for `s1`, `s2` members of `S` (not necessarily distinct).

I am using the following code:

```
def sumList(l):
    # generates a list of numbers which are sums of two elements of l
    sumL = []
    howlong = len(l)
    for i in range(howlong):
        for j in range(i+1):
            if not l[i]+l[j] in sumL:
                sumL.append(l[i]+l[j])
    return sumL
```

This works fine for short enough lists, but when handed a longer list (say, 5000 elements between 0 and 20000) goes incredibly slowly (20+ minutes).

Question: what is making this slow? My guess is that asking whether the sum is already a member of the list is taking some time, but I am a relative newcomer to both Python and programming, so I am not sure. I am also looking for suggestions on how to perform the task of producing `S + S` in a quick fashion.

Comment: Yes, the list lookup isn't a great way to do this -- try Python's [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python has a built-in type `set` that has very fast lookups.  You can't store duplicates or unhashable objects in a set, but since you want a set of integers, it's perfect for your needs.  In the below, I also use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to generate the pairs.

```
from itertools import product

def sums(l):
    return {x+y for x, y in product(l, repeat=2)}

print(sums([1, 2, 3, 4]))
# {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}
```

As to why your existing solution is so slow, you might want to look up the term "algorithmic complexity".  Basically, it's a way of categorizing algorithms into general groups based on how well they scale to many inputs.  Your algorithm is a `O(n^3)` algorithm (it will do about `n^3` comparisons).  In comparison, the `set` solution is `O(n^2)`. It accomplished this by discarding the need to check if a particular sum is already in the `set`.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and assistance.